# Get last element (based on names) in a list - LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I have this list:

Annie - P 
May - " " 
Annie - P
May - P

And I want to get the last element based on the names:

Annie - P
May - P

I have this code but it's either throwing an error: `The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` or I only get the very last element in the list (May - P).

```
class Passenger
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PassengerID { get; set; }
    public List<TravelDoc> TravelDocs { get; set; }
}

class TravelDoc
{
    public string DocType { get; set; }
    public int? DocNumber { get; set; }
}

List<Passenger> modList = new List<Passenger>()
    {

        new Passenger() { Name = "Annie", PassengerID = 0, 
                          TravelDocs = new List<TravelDoc>()
                          {
                            new TravelDoc() { DocNumber = 100, DocType = "P" }
                          }
                        },
        new Passenger() { Name = "May", PassengerID = 1, 
                          TravelDocs = new List<TravelDoc>()
                          {
                            new TravelDoc() { DocNumber = null, DocType = "" }
                          }
                        },      
        new Passenger() { Name = "Annie", PassengerID = 0, 
                          TravelDocs = new List<TravelDoc>()
                          {
                            new TravelDoc() { DocNumber = 100, DocType = "P" }
                          }
                        },
        new Passenger() { Name = "May", PassengerID = 1, 
                          TravelDocs = new List<TravelDoc>()
                          {
                            new TravelDoc() { DocNumber = 200, DocType = "P" }
                          }
                        }
    };
```

**Code (Throws an error)**

```
var passengersMod = modList.SelectMany(pax => pax.TravelDocs         
                    .Select(doc => new { Passenger = pax, TravelDoc = doc })
                    .Last())
                    .Dump();
```

**Code (Wrong Results)**

```
var passengersMod = modList.SelectMany(pax => pax.TravelDocs         
                    .Select(doc => new { Passenger = pax, TravelDoc = doc })
                    ).Last()
                    .Dump();
```

**Note:** Dump() is a LINQPad extension. :D

How can I get the result I wanted using LINQ?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Okay, it seems that most people gets confused with "based on names" condition. Sorry about that but unfortunately I could not think of any better words to describe the criteria (sorry). But Jon Hanna got what I meant, so thanks! Also I removed the "of anonymous types" from the title as suggested. Thanks again! :D

**Another Edit:**

I have another situation similar to this with slight difference. Yes, the list was group according to some criteria (in this example by names) but instead of needing the last item from each grouping, what I need is the nth item from each grouping.

I was able to get the nth from each grouping:

```
modList.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(g => g.ToList()[index])
```

Years after I asked this question, Jon's answer still helped me. How I wish I could upvote his answer twice! I hope this might help somebody else. :D

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you are trying to order by or what exactly you mean by "based on names"?

Comment: LOL. I think it actually helped me get it that it's nearly bed-time in this timezone and I went "TL;DR" to most of the question! :)

Comment: Haha. Sometimes trying to understand a particular problem too deeply gives way to overlooking the surface requirements. Lolz. Super thanks! You saved me from an incoming headache! :P

Comment: Yes, it's very easy to spend a long time complicating ones "almost there" solution and hence not seeing a solution that was simpler in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not ignore anonymous types and `SelectMany` and just do:

```
modList.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(g => g.Last())
```

It's got nothing to do with anonymous types as per your title, but it does result in the sort of results you mention at the start of the question.

Answer (score 1):

First off, SelectMany is used to aggregate multiple sets into a single set. Think of turning an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> into a single IEnumerable<int>. So the usage cannot be inferred because the Last method will return a single element that does not represent an IEnumerable object. Now I don't quite understand what you mean by "last elements based on name" but if you want to get the last N elements in your collection, you could do something like:

```
// This will return the last 2 elements in your collection.
modList.Skip(modList.Count() - 2);
```

Comment: True and I considered that at first, but Reverse carries the overhead of reversing the collection's order. Skip simply seeks past the elements. That's why I went with the code I did. Thanks for adding that for completeness though :)

Comment: I hoped you didn't read my comment, I thought my comment is not related to question and I deleted it.  BTW, I believe the overhead is not that much.

Comment: The overhead _can_ be a concern in situations where you have a more significant count of elements in the result set. Your approach of reversing the set then taking the last few elements would definitely be faster in the case when the count of the set was not a pre-calculated value(i.e: an Enumerable object that yields its results using an enumerator). I know it doesn't answer the question, but this information doesn't hurt to know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand how you're ordering the items, but I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
var passengersMod = modList.SelectMany(
    d => d.TravelDocs, (p, d) => new { Passenger = p, TravelDoc = d })
   .Last()
   .Dump();
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, thanks! If you don't mind, can you explain what you did here? I quite new in LINQ projections and aggregations. Why do you need to create d => d.TravelDocs? Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, upon second inspection... It only returns the last element which is May - P. What I need is Annie - P and May - P. Thanks for your answer though. :D

Comment: You could probably find better info around SO, but the short answer is that [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx) flattens each passengers list of travel docs  (the first parameter) and then applies a result selector (the second parameter) to get the final results.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you want.. your questions says "And I want to get the last element" but it looks like you want the last 2 elements?

Comment: Oh, ok will clarify the question. Thanks.